# Problem with If- Else Conditiones, How can I resolve it?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

The problem is that I want that the code shows the graph if the Value of "Recordinaciones" is > 1, and shows "No hay Recorinaciones Dobles" if  <1 but I have some strange issue. Hope someone can help me!
The problem is:

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Here it's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

doc = input('Ingresa el nombre del archivo: ')
print(f'Ingresaste {doc}')

df=pd.read_excel(doc+'.xlsx')
df['Recordinaciones'] = df.apply(lambda _: '', axis=1)
df['Cantidad'] = df.apply(lambda _: '', axis=1)

rcs=df[['Cliente','# Externo','Recordinaciones']].groupby(['Cliente','# Externo']).count().reset_index().sort_values(['Recordinaciones'],ascending=False)

Recoordinaciones = rcs['Recordinaciones']  
if Recoordinaciones > 1:                        # Pregunto si x es mayor a 1
    print(rcs[(rcs['Recordinaciones'] > 1)])    
else:
  print( "No hay Recorinaciones Dobles")            # cumple, ejecuto esto
```

Error Message

### Ingresa el nombre del archivo: Test Feb
Ingresaste Test Feb

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
11
12 Recoordinaciones = rcs['Recordinaciones']
---> 13 if Recoordinaciones > 1:                                                # Pregunto si x es mayor a 1
14     print(rcs[(rcs['Recordinaciones'] > 1)])
15 else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in **nonzero**(self)
1536     def **nonzero**(self):
1537         raise ValueError(
-> 1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).**name**} is ambiguous. "
1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
1540         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

[image]

Comment: you are comparing a type Series with a type int which doesn't really work. you should try the pandas .loc[] version to check each element or if you really want to print something everytime use the iterrows() method and check each element.

Comment: also next time just copy the text of your error message and code into your question, pictures of code are not great to work with :)

Comment: Maxxel I add  the error code, can you give me the example to use .loc, iterrows()?

Comment: I think you were wanting to do: `Recoordinaciones = len(rcs['Recordinaciones'])`?
The point is that rcs['Recordinaciones'] is a "Series" not a number so it cannot be  `> 1` or `== 1` it can have a shorter/longer length (number of elements in the series) than 1.

Comment: Recordinaciones its a number that normally round around 1 or 2, I only want to see the ones that are >1, and if there are not (no exist) >1 i want the message of "No hay Recorinaciones Dobles"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Recoordinaciones = rcs.loc[rcs['Recordinaciones'] > 1]['Recordinaciones'].tolist()

if len(Recoordinaciones) == 0:
    print('no values >1')
else:
    for r in Recoordinaciones: 
        print(r)
```

basically the loc function receives a condition with a boolean outcome and *locates* the rows where this condition is met.